# Оформление расписания

Tags: пунктуация

Какие знаки следует ставить при составлении расписания для отделения времени от запланированного занятия? Следует ли записывать занятие с прописной буквы?

12:00 поесть
13:00 Поспать
14:30: провести конференцию
15:00 — выйти на прогулку
16:00 — Заняться сольфеджио

Answer (score 0):

Табличный вариант расписания прост, нагляден и не требует особых знаний. Ваши варианты не бесспорны, они представляют собой фразу, а знания (или традиции), помогающие отказаться от таких решений, предписывают не начинать предложение с числительных, записанных *нашими* арабскими цифрами.

Если вид таблицы не устраивает, применяют разбивку текста красной строкой:

13:00

Отдых

14:30

Видеоконференция

Выравнивание по левому краю можно заменить выравниванием по центру страницы. Знаки препинания не ставятся, прописные желательны.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запись в строку считается ошибкой?

Comment: Не считается, но для составления расписания, а главное, практического пользования им не применяется как трудно читаемая масса.

Comment: А если записывать в столбик. Время — занятие, затем с красной строки время — занятие? В таком случае после указания времени безо всяких знаков препинания следует с прописной буквы записывать занятие?

Comment: Такая запись на строке (13:00 Поспать) не годится, если её части не разнести друг от друга. В итоге, отодвинув пробелами правую часть строк на несколько знаков, получим ту же таблицу, только без графики.